# Add table row for each table row in database table

Tags: php

I couldn't really find another  post about this problem. 
I am trying to add in html a new table row for every new table row I have in phpmyadmin table with php script.

My code is:

```
<?php

    if($check == true)
    {
    echo" <a href='php/logout.php' class='subpages'>Logout</a>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    FileName: <a href='../uploads/$filename'>$filename</a>
                </td>
                <td>";
                     $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("phplogin"); // select DB
                    $getcomment = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM files WHERE name='$filename'");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcomment))
                    {
                        echo"Comment: ".$row['comment']." </td>
                                </tr>";
                    }
        }
?>
```

The check at the begging checks if a file is actualy uploaded if it is a connection is made to get the name of the file and the comment attached to it.

Then finaly when the info has been taken I want to make a table row and 2 colusm for FileName and Comment. The result of my code replaces the already created row with a new one.

Is there a way to create a new row for each new File and Comment that has been taken with PHP script only ?

Comment: shouldn't that be taken care of using INSERT during the time of the upload?

Comment: you're missing `echo '<tr><td>'` in the loop

Comment: The phpadmin table aready has the data. Here I just select the file that was just uploaded. I can provide the code I used to insert filename and comment.

EDIT: I am not I use the top echo to create the <tr> <td> and the bottom echo to close them.

Comment: I'm not grasping the question fully then. Try what twentylemon said.

Comment: Hmm. Okay I will try to explain myself better. I have a table in phpadmin that saves unique id, filename, comment. A person can upload a file and add comment to it. When a file is uploaded I want that file to appear on a newly created row in a table in html. My code replaces the old row with the new one and only shows the new file.

Comment: *Hm....*, ok I think you're probably looking to use `mysql_insert_id()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php if the question is about getting the last inserted entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... please let us know is it working or not...

```
if($check == true)
{
    echo" <a href='php/logout.php' class='subpages'>Logout</a>
            <table><tbody><tr>
                 <th>File Name</th>
                 <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    FileName: <a href='../uploads/$filename'>$filename</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                ";
                     $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("phplogin"); // select DB
                    $getcomment = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM files WHERE name='$filename'",$connect);
                    $res = mysql_fetch_row($getcomment);
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($getcomment);

                    if ($num_row > 0){

                        for ($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++){

                        echo "<tr><td><Comment: ".$res[$i]."</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: @Nikola Grigorov you are Welcome. To check whether the row is affected or not use row num func which is easy to implement. If satisfied accept the answer.